# Java Perf Map Agent "Could not find Agent_OnLoad function"

Tags: jvm, perf

On oracle jdk1.8.0_251 I have error when trying to use perf tool helper library "libperfmap.so" ([perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/perf-map-agent))

```
taskset -c 1,7 java -XX:+PreserveFramePointer -agentpath:$WORK_HOME/perf-map-agent/out/libperfmap.so=unfold,msig -cp $WORK_HOME/HARDWARE/xx/target/xx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.xx.xx.logic.xx.xxTest 0 50
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find Agent_OnLoad function in the agent library: /home/username/Documents/JINT/perf-map-agent/out/libperfmap.so
```

Another variant of the error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find Agent_OnLoad function in the agent library: /home/username/Documents/lowlatency/xxx/JINT/perf-map-agent/out/libperfmap.so
```

Comment: Did you compile `perf-map-agent` yourself or take prebuilt binaries?

Comment: Yes I did that. Compiled with java 1.8.0_251 which is > 1.8.60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perf-map-agent` currently does not support loading as `-agentpath`. See [issue #27](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/perf-map-agent/issues/27) for the previous discussion on the topic.

There are also two pull requests ([#63](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/perf-map-agent/pull/63), [#85](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/perf-map-agent/pull/85)) adding `Agent_OnLoad`  functionality; you may try one of those.

Meanwhile I can recommend [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) as an alternative. It supports both `-agentpath` mode and attach in runtime. It also supports perf events and generates flame graphs out of the box without 3rd party software.